# During testing, when tested with correct user input, I get "Invalid credentials"

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using just phone number alone as the only field for login. 
Authentication does not seem to work well even when supplied with correct user input.

ERROR WHEN I CONFIGURE THE AUTH BACKENDS:

```
 File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def logins(request):
    phone_number = request.data.get("phone_number")
    if phone_number is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide your phone number'},
                        status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(phone_number=phone_number)
    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                        status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import User

class LoginBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        phone_number= kwargs['phone_number']
        user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        if user:
            return user
        else:
            return None
```

settings.py

```
from .backends import LoginBackend
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'findr.backends.LoginBackend']
```

Comment: Can you tell us what does not work? Is phone_number read correctly? Is it when you try to authenticate?

Comment: Yeah. It's correctly read..

Comment: I guess you wrote your own authentication backend? Can we see it please? :-)

Comment: No I did not write any authentication backend.

Comment: Well if you did not, Django is not supposed to know that a user should authenticate with his phone number! Django will try to authenticate with default credentials: `username` and `password`.

Comment: Hmmm.... I see, so I will have to write an authentication backend. Thanks.

Comment: ok! not a big deal, don't worry. If my answer satisfies you, please consider to upvote it and tag it as accepted so your topic can be closed! Good luck 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comments on your question, I suggest you to write your own `django` authentification backend:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

You have to tell Django how someone should be authenticated:

- with `username` and `password`?
- with `phone_number` and `password`?

This has to be explicit (and do not forget to add this new backend to your `settings.py` file!).

Comment: Having issues writing the back-end authentication for the endpoint. Can you help out? The docs is not helping.

Comment: I am not going to do your work, but I can help. What issue do you face with? What did you do already? What's not clear in the doc?

Comment: I have made edits to the code I have up there so as to reflect the changes.